# Why have "clamp", "clamp.", and "clamp!" in Julia?

Tags: julia

Julia has [two methods for limiting variables to ranges of numbers](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/base/math/#Base.Math.clamp): `clamp` and `clamp!`. With dot notation, `clamp.` can also be used for the same functionality.

`clamp` limits a scalar to an interval defined by two values.

`clamp.` operates element-by-element on an array to limit each value to that interval. It will also work on ints and floats that are not in an array.

`clamp!` operates on an entire array to limit each value to the interval.

Why have three functions to do the same thing? Is there any reason to use `clamp!` or `clamp`, when `clamp.` will handle both scalars and arrays?

Comment: it is one fucntion, `.` and `!` are modifiers, they apply to any function

Comment: Not quite. `!` is not a modifier. They denote functions that mutate their inputs. `.` is the broadcasing operator to make our life easier. So you have 2 functions: `clamp` and `clamp!`. The first one returns a copy of your array clamped, while the second one modifies the original array. If you add `.` then you apply that functions elementwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually you have two functions `clamp` and `clamp!`.

Function `clamp` accepts only scalars for all arguments. So the only accepted usage is like `clamp(3, 4, 5)`.

Function `clamp!` accepts an array as a first argument and scalars as second and third arguments. It modifies its first argument in place.

Call `clamp.(x, lo, hi)` is a broadcasted application of function `clamp`.

This means that `clamp.(x, 4, 5)` will create a new vector (most of the time - see a comment below for an exception), while `clamp!(x, 4, 5)` would update the contents of `x`.

Also you can write something like e.g. `clamp.([1,2,3], [3,1,6], [4,5,7])` and broadcast all arguments, which `clamp!` does not allow.

Finally, those two expressions produce the same result:

```
x .= clamp.(x, lo, hi)
```

and

```
clamp!(x, lo, hi)
```

if `lo` and `hi` are scalars as both modify `x` in place (`.=` assignment tells Julia to modify it in place).

EDIT:

One more important difference between `clamp.` and `clamp!` (being a natural consequence that `clamp!` is in-place) is that broadcasting `clamp` works on immutable argument, e.g. `clamp.(0:0.1:1, 0.25, 0.75)` will work, while `clamp!(0:0.1:1, 0.25, 0.75)` throws an error.

Comment: It seems like `clamp!` is redundant, then. Are there any cases where it cannot be replaced with  `clamp`?

Comment: I would say it is redundant and it should have been cleaned up with Julia 1.0. However, you can think of obscure codes where it makes a difference, but they are rare e.g. `clamp!(rand.(5), 0.25, 0.75)` works while `clamp.(rand.(5), 0.25, 0.75)`.fails and you have to break broadcast fusion e.g. like this `clamp.(identity(rand.(5)), 0.25, 0.75)`.